# How to integrate RESTful webservice with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I have a profile create page like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function validateMe(){

               var xmlhttp;
               var userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
               var userPwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
               //alert(userEmail);
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("responds").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

                xmlhttp.open("POST","api.php?email="+userEmail+"&pwd="+userPwd,true);
                xmlhttp.send();  
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <table>
                <tr><td colspan="2">Login</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="validateMe();"/><td></td></tr>
            </table>
            <div id="responds"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to use the RESTful web service with php and ajax to insert these data into my MySql database.

How can I implement this. Can anyone help me out to do this.

Comment: What have you read and tried so far? We don't know where to start explaining without some indication where you get stuck..

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to use the jQuery Javascript framework. With it, it made dead simple to make AJAX requests and getting the input values (without worrying of the web browser, etc).

Second, I don't see any RESTful web service here. It's a simple POST form.

So please, details your question :)